# unable to restart Apache2

Tags: server, apache2, php

I've been trying to start/restart Apache2 and been getting the same error over and over. Already look up in many questions or problems, but no one was able to solve my problem. Using Ubuntu 18.04 with Apache2 and php7.0.

So, the problem is that when I execute the comand:

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
I get this error:

Restarting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.serviceJob for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
failed!

Executing `systemctl status --no-pager --full apache2` returns:

```
May 19 18:32:25 lnxcp.cp016.net systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
May 19 18:32:25 lnxcp.cp016.net apachectl[13384]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 17 of /home/admin/conf/web/essed.it.apache2.conf:
May 19 18:32:25 cp016.net apachectl[13384]: Invalid command 'php_admin_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
May 19 18:32:25 lnxcp.cp016.net apachectl[13384]: Action 'start' failed.
May 19 18:32:25 lnxcp.cp016.net apachectl[13384]: The Apache error log may have more information.
May 19 18:32:25 lnxcp.cp016.net systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 19 18:32:25 lnxcp.cp016.net systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 19 18:32:25 lnxcp.cp016.net systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I'm a newbie in Linux/Ubuntu, so someone can help me? thank you!

Comment: You have `Syntax error on line 17 of /home/admin/conf/web/essed.it.apache2.conf` Do you have PHP installed in your system? Have you enabled PHP module, e.g. `a2enmod php7.2`

Comment: yes, php is installed and enabled

Comment: You should check if the the `libapache2-mod-php7.0` package is installed on your system.